# cannot change wallpaper in Gnome

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I recently installed Gnome on my Dell OptiPlex 755 computer. Everything seems to work, but I cannot add a wallpaper image on my desktop. I tried Wallch, to no avail. Is there a trick to adding wallpaper to Gnome, or is this system simply meant to use a jet-black background?

Answer (score 0):

In **Settings** > **Background** you'll get options to change desktop background and lock screen background. But it only allows to choose images from a limited number of directories. If you want the full freedom to choose images from any directory, use **GNOME Tweak Tool** and look for **Desktop** menu.